# Can I add breakpoint on CreateProcess in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints

Can I add breakpoint on windows CreateProcess API in Visual studio like I can do in Windbg?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes - Go "Debug / New breakpoint / Break at function..." and paste this:

```
{,,kernel32.dll}_CreateProcessW@40
```

into the Function box.

That assumes a Unicode build - replace `W` with `A` for ANSI builds.

A bit of explanation: the `@40` piece is part of the stdcall calling convention, and gives the number of bytes of parameters that the function takes.  In win32, this is almost always 4 times the number of parameters.  The underscore is also part of the stdcall calling convention.

A related note: sometimes the name of the function as seen by the debugger is different from its real name - see this blog post for an example, and how to find the right name to use: [Setting a Visual Studio breakpoint on a Win32 API function in user32.dll](http://entrian.com/blog/setting-a-visual-studio-breakpoint-on-a-win32-api-function-in-user32dll/)

Comment: Better to break on both. Because of the funky non-const behavior of CreateProcessW, even Unicode applications might call CreateProcessA. The CreateProcess macro doesn't hide the underlying two function declarations so they remain callable. This also applies to similar macros for other function pairs.

Comment: One additional thing to note is that you have to download `kernel32.dll` symbols first. You can do that from context menu inside Debug/Windows/Modules.

Comment: explanation of {,,,} syntax is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wztycb7f(v=vs.100).aspx note that for whatever reason the article doesn't exist for visual studio higher than vs2010